# Issue with plotting EC50 value on dose response with drm() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a dose-response curve with the measured data and lines that highlight EC50. However, I am having trouble plotting the EC value correctly. Script below.

Here is my script; create data set, compute dose-response model, calculate EC50. I think predict values for higher resolution to get a nicer curve on my graph. No issues here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(drc)

#load data
data <- tribble(
  ~concentration, ~replicate, ~survival,
  0, 'A', 31.03,
  0, 'B', 24.14,
  0, 'C', 31.03,
  0.047, 'A', 30.00,
  0.047, 'B', 23.33,
  0.047, 'C', 6.67,
  0.0895,'A',23.33,
  0.0895, 'B', 16.67,
  0.0895, 'C', 20.00,
  0.453, 'A', 13.33,
  0.453, 'B', 23.33,
  0.453, 'C', 30.00,
  0.91, 'A', 26.67,
  0.91, 'B', 16.67,
  0.91, 'C', 13.33,
  4.39, 'A', 0.00,
  4.39, 'B', 0.00,
  4.39, 'C', 0.00,
  8.97, 'A', 0.00,
  8.97, 'B', 0.00,
  8.97, 'C', 0.00,)

glimpse(data)  
  
#general dose-response model 
curve_fit<- drm(
  formula = survival ~ concentration,
  data=data,
  fct=LL.4(names=c('hill', 'min_value', 'max_value', 'ec_50'))
)

curve_fit

#predict values for the range of tested concentrations at a finer resolution
data_predicted <- tibble(
  concentration = seq(min(data$concentration), max(data$concentration), 0.01)
)

data_predicted$predicted <- predict(
  curve_fit,
  newdata = as.data.frame(data_predicted)
)

glimpse(data_predicted)
```

This is where I am getting the issue with my plot. I am trying to plot the observed data (reps of survival for each concentration), plot my dose-response curve, and then plot the EC50. I think the observed data and model is fine, but the EC50 value is not; not intercepting the y axis correctly or hitting my curve.

```
#plot dose response with EC50 on graph
lines_to_highlight_ec50 <- tribble(
  ~x,   ~xend, ~y,   ~yend,
  ec50, ec50,  -Inf, 0.5,
  0,    ec50,  0.5,  0.5
)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    data = lines_to_highlight_ec50,
    aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
    color = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed', size = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(data = data_predicted, aes(x = concentration, y = predicted), size = 1) +
  geom_point(
    data = data,
    aes(x = concentration, y = survival, fill = replicate),
    shape = 21, size = 3, color = 'white', show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  annotate(
    'text', x = 0.01, y = 0.5, label = paste0('EC50: ', round(ec50, digits = 3), ' mg/L'),
    hjust = 0, vjust = -1
  ) +
  scale_x_log10(name = 'Measured Lithium (mg/L)', breaks = unique(ata$concentration)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Survival (%)') +
  theme_bw()

ggsave('dose_response_curve.png', p, height = 4, width = 6)
p
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When I try to run your code (specifically the `lines_to_highlight_ec50` definition) I get `object ec50 not found`. You don't seem to have included how you calculated `ec50` in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

The EC50 is the value of x such that the corresponding value of y is the middle of the two asymptote values. You have to extract this value of y (`ymid` below), and replace your `0.5` with this value:

```r
#plot dose response with EC50 on graph
coeffs <- coef(curve_fit)
ec50 <- coeffs[4]
ymid <- mean(coeffs[2:3])

lines_to_highlight_ec50 <- tribble(
  ~x,   ~xend, ~y,   ~yend,
  ec50, ec50,  -Inf, ymid,
  0,    ec50,  ymid,  ymid
)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    data = lines_to_highlight_ec50,
    aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
    color = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed', linewidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = data_predicted, aes(x = concentration, y = predicted), 
    linewidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = data,
    aes(x = concentration, y = survival, fill = replicate),
    shape = 21, size = 3, color = 'white', show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  annotate(
    'text', x = 0.01, y = ymid, 
    label = paste0('EC50: ', round(ec50, digits = 3), ' mg/L'),
    hjust = 0, vjust = -1
  ) +
  scale_x_log10(
    name = 'Measured Lithium (mg/L)', breaks = unique(data$concentration)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Survival (%)') +
  theme_bw()
```